# Apply Ito Lemma and find process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a big problem in understanding and deriving partial derivatives.
I would like to understand the logic behind deriving partial derivatives for some exemplary processes. I have a few examples which I would like to understand 'how to' derive.

E.g. Basing on Ito process:

**dG = ( ∂G/∂S * µS +  ∂G/∂t +  1/2* ∂^2G/∂S^2  * ^2 *S^2) dt + ∂G/∂S * S dz**

I have some examples of processes that should follow Ito process. For The examples below I know the solutions but I would like to know how to get to them.

**The Following processes should be expressed in terms of Ito:**

a) y = S^2

b)y = e^S

c)  y = e^(r(T-t)/S

d) the hard one: 
Process is given as  dS = ( r B - rA ) S dt + S dz 
which is  the process for a price of currency A expressed in terms of the price of currency B. We should determine process followed by the price of currency B expressed in terms of currency A.

Answers:
I would like to understand how partial derivatives are derived in the form of:

∂G/ ∂S

∂G/ ∂t

∂^2 G / ∂S^2

The latter, how to insert derivatives in form of above to Ito process - I can fully perform but I have so many doubts how the derivatives should be derived.

**For instance the asnwers for a) and d) are:**

**a) y = S^2**

Partial derivatives would be:

∂y/∂S =  2S

∂^2 y / ∂S^2 = 2

∂y/∂t =  0

Final Ito process followed:

dy = (2µS^2 + ^2 S^2)dt + 2 S^2dz

**d) X = 1/S**

Partial derivatives would be:

∂X/ ∂S = (-1/S^2)

∂F/ ∂t = 0

∂^2 X / ∂S^2 =   (2/S^3)

Final Ito process followed:

dX = ( (rB - rA)S  *  (-1/S^2) +  1/2 * (2/S^3) * ^2S^2) dt + (-1/S^2)  S dz

Could somebody explain point by point how this has been achieved? 
If I have provided too many examples (a to d), it will be enough to show me one of the points from a - c and point d.

I will fully appreciate because I have no clue.

Comment: Is $S$ your Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes it is. I mean for sure

Comment: Please, anybody who could help??